# Transform data to marginal uniform distribution

Tags: r, uniform

I have results estimating of ARIMA - GARCH (residual probability is std).

I check out [A Short, Comprehensive, Practical Guide to Copulas by Atillio Meucci](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1847864). The paper provides further references in case.

But how to transform this data (with informations from estimated ARIMA - GARCH model) to marginal uniform distribution N~(0,1)? I don't know how to code in R, can anyone help me this code?

Comment: `rugarch` and `rmgarch`.